# Forwarding from godaddy is not showing my heroku website properly

Tags: reactjs, heroku, godaddy-api

[So this is my heroku website. Under 600px, it should change to my mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgPc6.png)

[but my website on godaddy that is forwarding is not reflecting that change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4vKm.png)

how can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

its because the forwarding places the website into an Iframe and so it looses it mobile responsive css queries.

i just had the same problem with my website.

reverted back to unmasked because of it. now looking for a better way of having my URL